# Kotlin Android vs. Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm a years-long Java Android developer that recently started writing apps in Kotlin and Compose. I like it for the most part, and I'm thinking of proposing Kotlin Multiplatform to the rest of my team for a small tool we're writing.

What differences in project setup are there in vanilla Kotlin vs. Multiplatform? Assuming we wanted the app to work for Android and Desktop (in that priority order), would it be better to write an Android Kotlin/Compose app and migrate later, or start the project as Multiplatform from the ground up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Android app, and you decide to add desktop support, most of your time will be spent migrating to KMP dependencies.

So you need to know which libs are supported by desktop - I think the main thing will be navigation, as Jetpack Navigation doesn't support KMP, so you need to choose a KMP supported navigation library. I would have gone for [Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose), but you can also look for other solutions in this [list](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries) of KMM libraries.

I would suggest you start with the KMP project, add the desktop target, but do not test/run it. Write everything you can in the common module, this will prevent you from using android-only code there - you can still use it in `androidMain`. Adding desktop support later will be a much easier task in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice [template tool](https://kmp.jetbrains.com/) for new project directly from Jetbrains. Just pick platform and then you can compare the difference. In short - there is not much difference in project setup (few lines of code) also assuming that you also want to use [Compose Multiplaform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform) for UI. For navigation and ViewModel I would pick [PreCompose](https://github.com/Tlaster/PreCompose) because it's very similar to Jetpack Navigation which is not KMP ready. The rest of the libraries for networking (Ktor), depedency injection (Koin) etc. are mostly KMP ready so there is not so much difference to start developing both Android and desktop application at once.